# Структура БД учета клиентов

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Суть следующая, нужно сделать БД учета звонков клиентов и учета заказов.Манипулирования с БД будет происходить через PHP.
Клиенты звонят и спрашивают цену на выполнения строительных работ.
Менеджер фиксирует все эти заявки(звонки) от клиента в таблицу слудующей стуктуры.

```
--Таблица заявки --
-id
-Имя
-Фамилия
-Телефон
-адрес
-тип работы (id_type - внешний ключ с таблици типы)
-Статус(Принято,отказано,заказано,дорого,клиент думает)
-Дата заявки
```

Нужно сделать так, когда статус будет "Заказано" то создавать, нового клиента (в таблице клиентов) на основе данных из таблици заявки (ФИО, телефон, адресс, и еще пару данных). Пока статус другой, нечего не делать.
Проблема заключается в следующем, клиент через время может опять позвонить, и эту заявку нужно зафиксировать, соотвественно если статус клиента будет опять "Заказано" то мы его будем заносить в таблицу клиентов, и получится дублирования одного и того клиента.

Как это лучше всех с проектировать. И еще если статус заявки будет "Заказано", то еще будут вносится некоторые данные, вплоть до расчета стоимости работы. И я думаю нужно ли заносить их в таблицу заявки (по умолчанию заполнять нулями поля),  или создать новую.

Comment: 1) При добавлении нового клиента в таблицу клиентов проводить проверку на существование клиента с такими же, допустим, фамилией + телефоном. Добавление клиента лучше всего делать триггером, конечно. 2) Смотря какие данные

Comment: А зачем вам две таблицы клиентов?

Comment: Таблица будет одна для клиентов.
Основная суть таблици клиентов: это для статистики просмотра заказов, плюс для облегчения заполнения данных Заявки (автоподгрузка по телефону к примеру)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос лежит не столько в области дизайна, сколько в области администрирования. Поясню: таблица клиентов это т.н. мастер данные, которые критичны к дублям. Какую бы систему проверок ни организовывать, зловредные юзеры найдут способ завести что-нибудь типа:

- ЧП Пупкин
- ИЧП Пупкин
- ПБОЮЛ Пупкин
- Пупкин ЧП
- ЧП Пупкинд
- Ч.П. Пупкин
- ну и.т.д.

Более-менее проверенный паттерн здесь такой:

1. Кидаем новых клиентов в промежуточную таблицу, например `tmp_customer`
2. Поручаем Светке Соколовой (в идеале в больших организациях имеется *отдел Мастер Данных*) ежедневно организовывать выгрузку новых записей из `tmp_customer` в `customer` с соответствующей проверкой на наличие дублей.

Comment: а если в день будут регистрироватся 50000 пользователей?

Comment: Тогда вместо Светки Соколовой будет целый отдел

Comment: В том то и дело, Светка Соколова будет одна вносить данные. Отдел это много )

Answer (score 1):

> и получится дублирования одного и того клиента.

Эту проблему проще всего решить созданием клиента при первом обращении, как составную часть процедуры фиксации обращения. При этом по мере ввода информации оператором вводимые данные сверяются с существующей базой клиентов, и если введённой информации достаточно для отбора небольшого (навскидку - не более 4-5) количества записей о клиентах, то выводятся сведения о них с предложением выбрать из существующих (что не исключает продолжения заполнения формы и ввода клиента как нового). Возможно, что после выбора ещё придётся и корректировать (скажем, у клиента со времени прошлых заказов сменился номер телефона). Если же соответствий много - выводится только количество совпадений.